# What browsers is Google Web Toolkit tested against?

Tags: gwt, cross-browser

I'm very interested in GWT and I'm curious which browsers it's tested against? The info is not painfully easy enough for me to find and I haven't gotten an answer on the group (I haven't waited long but messages get buried there fast).

This is really important to me... I would assume google's standards are high (probably higher than mine) but I'd like to know more.

See also [YUI Graded Browser support](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Cross-Browser support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideUserInterface.html#DevGuideCrossBrowserSupport):

> GWT shields you from worrying too much about cross-browser incompatibilities. If you stick to built-in widgets and composites, your applications will work similarly on the most recent versions of Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Safari. (Opera, too, most of the time.) DHTML user interfaces are remarkably quirky, though, so make sure to test your applications thoroughly on every browser.

---

Out of personal experience I can tell you that almost all browsers I've tested will work:

- Opera 9 or better;
- Firefox 2 or better;
- Internet Explorer 6 or better;
- Safari 3 or better;
- Konqueror - as bundled in KDE 4.3 - the 3.5.x series does not seem to work;

Comment: In other words: nternet Explorer, Firefox, and Safari. (Opera, too, most of the time.)

Comment: Yes, yes, just filling in the links :-)

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a more exact answer. Maybe since the commits are all done by Google employees only they can really answer this. Anyway, I think it would be really useful information and probably really impressive since Google is using it for important projects (like the Wave client). I'm not trying to get out cross browser testing but it'd be nice to have an idea of what testing has been done is and in what environments. Short of that can anyone draw from personal experience and point a finger at an environment that is poorly supported by GWT or is everything usually pretty tight, etc?

Comment: @Mike - I've added my personal experience with some of the browsers.